# Javascript class this.x is not a function when calling function from inside class

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I have a button which, when pressed, should call a function which calls another function. this is inside a class.

```
class cat{
    constructor(){
        this.event_listener();
    }

    log_2(){
        console.log("cat 2");
    }
    log_1(){
        console.log("cat 1");
        this.log_2();
    }

    event_listener(){
        document.getElementById("cat_button").addEventListener("click", this.log_1);
    }
}

let cat1 = new cat();
```

The first function, this.log_1(), is called when the button is pressed and outputs "cat 1" as expected, but then the error

```
this.log_2 is not a function
```

appears on the console, although log_2() is defined within the class. How can I structure this so that log_2() is recognised as a function?

Comment: You haven't made `log2()` a property of the class (a class method). You've just made it a standalone function.

Comment: Try `.addEventListener("click", this.log_1.bind(this))` or `.addEventListener("click", event => this.log_1())`

Comment: you will need to bind

Comment: Modern browsers support this method syntax, which removes the need to bind: https://jsfiddle.net/n2dtysuc/

Answer (score 1):

`this` is what called the function. In this instance an event called the function so `this` refers to the event.

What you'll want to do is bind the method before using is as a reference. Now `this` will refer to the instance of the class.

```
event_listener(){
  this.log_1 = this.log_1.bind(this)

  document.getElementById("cat_button").addEventListener("click", this.log_1);
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate. Please check for dupes before posting an answer.

Comment: "*`this` is what called the function. In this instance an event called the function so `this` refers to the event."* That's not correct. `this` will actually be the element that the handler is bound to.